# reading a file in C: leading zeros

Tags: c, text-files, scanf, fgets, leading-zero

In my program I'm trying to read two values per line from a textfile.
It works well with my code below, but when I face numbers with leading zeros, it stores every zero as one value.

I want to be able to read in e.g. **"007"** as plain **"7"**, but I still want to be able to read a **"0"** as a value.

Anyone could help me improving my code or point out what/where it could be improved?

thanks in advance

**valuelist.txt**

```
55 009
63 10
12 0
```

**output**

```
counter: 0 | Value A: 55 Value B: 0 
counter: 1 | Value A: 9 Value B: 0 
counter: 2 | Value A: 9 Value B: 0 
counter: 3 | Value A: 63 Value B: 0 
counter: 4 | Value A: 10 Value B: 0 
counter: 5 | Value A: 12 Value B: 0 
counter: 6 | Value A: 0 Value B: 0
```

**main**

```
int main(void) {

        char name[] = "valuelist.txt";
        unsigned int counter = 0;
        unsigned int lines = 3;
        unsigned int num;
        unsigned int numtwo;


        FILE* ff = fopen(name,"r");
        if(ff == NULL) {
             fprintf(stderr, "Error \n");
            return -1;
        }

        char *tempp = (char*) malloc(lines + 1 );

        while(fgets(tempp,lines+1,ff) != NULL){

              sscanf(tempp,"%u %u",&num, &numtwo);

              printf("counter: %u | ",counter);
              printf("Value A: %u ",num);
              printf("Value B: %u \n",numtwo);

              counter++;
        }
        free(tempp);
        tempp = NULL;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code seems to do as you would expect.  Please post the contents of "valuelist.txt" along with the expected and actual output.  Also, this code will not compile as is because `countlines`, `num`, and `numtwo` are not defined.

Comment: Why count _lines_???

Comment: ...and then read `lines*2` bytes but there are only `lines+1` bytes?

Comment: @dbush updated the file + the current output, think you see whats wrong.. – David Dabrue just now   edit

Comment: @PaulOgilvie counting lines, because line length may differ later

Comment: Also: `sscanf()` returns a value. You could use that.

Comment: set  `lines` to a reasonable (constant!) value, like `255`. It looks like you are reading few characters only

Comment: If you want to know the length of a line, `lines` is a bad name. It indicates that you count lines, which is what you don't do.

Comment: Please don't make your question a moving target by changing relevant parts of the code invalidating most commands and answers!

Comment: With `lines = 3` you cannot read a line holding `55 009`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your updated code and data, the problem is certainly that the value of `lines` is too small for your usage.  You are using it to measure how much space you need for your `tempp` buffer, but that requires a maximum line *width* (plus one for the newline and another for the terminator).  You are instead giving it a line *count*, and that of a file having only a few lines.  Therefore `fgets()` is breaking up your lines across multiple calls.

You indeed could pre-scan the file to find an appropriate width, then allocate that much, but you're going to a lot of trouble here to use `fgets` instead of `fscanf`.  There are indeed reasons to prefer that for many problems, but yours does not look like one of them.  You would save yourself considerable trouble and code by doing this instead:

```
unsigned num, numtwo;
while (fscanf(ff, "%u%u", &num, &numtwo) == 2) {
    // update counter, print results, etc...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't allocated enough space to read in each line.  You're using the *number of lines* as the *length of a line*, but these are not the same.

You allocate 4 bytes (`lines + 1`) for `ttemp`, which you use to read in a line.  However the first line of text has 6 characters in it.  So the first call to `fgets` only reads the first 3 bytes, namely `"55 "`.  That's what then gets parsed by `sscanf`.  The next call gets the next 3 bytes, namely `"09\n"` and stops reading at the newline, so just the first number gets parsed out.

Since you use `fgets` in a loop to read lines and print the contents, you actually don't need to know how many lines there are.  You do however need to know the maximum length of a line.  Since you're reading two decimal integers, 30 bytes should be enough to read a full line.  So make a fixed buffer of that size:

```
    char tempp[30];
    while(fgets(tempp,sizeof(tempp),ff) != NULL){
        ...
```

Comment: Nitpick: `fgets(tempp, 4, ff)` reads at most *3* bytes from the file, not 4 (and appends a null terminator after the last byte read).

Comment: first of all, thanks for the explanation. what if there are like twenty leading zeros? my problem is, that due to the program that creates the valuelist.txt i don't know how much leading zeros there will be..

Comment: @JohnBollinger Good catch.  Fixed.

Comment: @DavidDabrue  If you can't predict how log a line will be but you know there are two values per line, you may be better off using `fscanf` directly as suggested by John Bollinger.

Comment: with every leading zero the line gets longer or am i wrong?

Comment: @DavidDabrue Yes, every additional character means more characters in the line, i.e. the line is longer.

Comment: @DavidDabrue, if you do not have a firm upper bound on line width in advance, and if you furthermore refuse to use `fscanf`, then you could consider reading your file one byte at a time via `fgetc()`, and doing your own numeric parsing.  It wouldn't be that hard.  It is certainly possible to adapt dynamically to input line length without pre-scanning the whole file, but that's a bit messy, and a lot more complicated than just parsing unsigned decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your fundamental problem is your `lines` variable.  It is way too small.  (Was it supposed to be "line size"?)

I would recommend that you get rid of the `lines` variable, the `tempp` variable, and the `malloc` call.  Declare a single array

```
char line[1000];
```

1000 characters should be plenty long for any imaginable input.  Then your loop can be

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), ff) != NULL) { ...
```

The rest of your code looks okay.  With this change, you should stop having problems with your numbers getting weirdly broken up.